# How to iterate over children with for-loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, children

I want to iterate over all childs of a jQuery's `.children()` return value, like this:

```
var childs = $element.children();        
for (var i = 1; i < childs.length - 1; i++)
    childs__.foo();
```

What do I have to write in the 3 line instead of `__`, to access the i-th child?

I want this becaus I want to access the (i-1)-th and (i+1)-th child in the loop, like this:

```
var childs = $element.children();        
for (var i = 1; i < childs.length - 1; i++)
{
    childs<<i>>.css('height', childs<<i - 1>>.height());
    childs<<i>>.css('width', childs<<i + 1>>.width());
}
```

So I assume the `each()` function will not work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`childs` is a [javascript array](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp). So you access objects within the array by `childs[indexOfElement]`. In your case `childs[i]`.

```
var childs = $element.children();        
for (var i = 1; i < childs.length - 1; i++)
    childs[i].foo();
```

and

```
var childs = $element.children();        
for (var i = 1; i < childs.length - 1; i++)
{
    childs[i].css('height', childs[i-1].height());
    childs[i].css('width', childs[i+1].width());
}
```

*BUT*: Your code has an error. The element from the children collection is NOT a jQuery object. It's just an DOM element. So you have to wrap them in `$(...)` to use jQuery functions. So your code will become:

```
var childs = $element.children();        
for (var i = 1; i < childs.length - 1; i++)
{
    var thisElement = $(childs[i]);
    var next = $(childs[i+1]);
    var prev = $(childs[i-1]);
    thisElement.css('height', prev.height());
    thisElement.css('width', next.width());
}
```

PS. It should be named `children`. :)

Comment: you should clarify that the OP would access the pure DOM node in this case, no jQuery object.

Comment: @jAndy Yep, just realized that myself, after re-reading and updated the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Strictly speaking, a jQuery object is not an array, it is *array-like*.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be easier with this selector http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/ ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the each() function, and use "this" to get the current object. Then you can use the next() and prev() functions instead of i+1 and i-1 respectively. I haven't tested the code so it may or may not work; hopefully points in the right direction :)

```
jQuery.each($element.children(), function() {
{
    $(this).css('height', $(this).prev().height());
    $(this).css('width', $(this).next().width());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `each()` function will work, take a look at this:

```
$('#something').children().each(function(index) { 

    $(this).css('width',  (parseInt($(this).css('width').replace('px', '')) + index) + "px");

    // to access the previous and next element:
    $(this).prev().css('width', '100px');
    $(this).next().css('width', '200px');

});
```

That will modify the width, adding the index as a pixel on each iteration - just to demo how to get the index.

Comment: so how do I access the (i-1)-th and (i+1)-th child in the loop?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show that using .prev() and .next()

Answer (score 1):

Use [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the one at the specified index of the matched dom elements set.

```
var childs = $element.children();        
for (var i = 1; i < childs.length - 1; i++)
{
    childs.eq(i).css('height', childs.eq(i - 1).height());
    childs.eq(i).css('width', childs.eq(i + 1).width());
}
```

and the  another simple approach is to achieve this without for loop use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
jQuery.each($element.children(), function() {
{
    $(this).css('height', this.prev().height());
    $(this).css('width', this.next().width());
}
```

Comment: "It's called .prev." as pimvdb mentioned :), but +1 for eq

Comment: and `this` is not a jQuery object so `.css()` does not exist. it should be `$(this).css()`.